# Javascript onfocus event handler will only allow me to carry out one function

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid, onfocus

I'm a bit of a rookie with Javascript so I apologise now if the answer is something obvious. My problem is that, on focusing on a given textarea, I want to both clear its contents and change the display value of a separate div from 'none' to 'block'. Doing these things separately wasn't a problem.

Clear contents:

```
onfocus="if (this.value == 'Update your status') {this.value = '';}"
```

and changing the display property of the separate div:

```
onfocus="displayControls();"
<script type="text/javascript">
            function displayControls() {
                 if (document.getElementById('statusUpdaterControls').style.display == "none") {
                     document.getElementById('statusUpdaterControls').style.display = "block";
                }; 
            }; 
</script>
```

When I have then tried to combine the two, either in the onfocus event of the textarea, or in the displayControls() function above like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayControls() {
                    if (document.getElementById('statusUpdater').value == 'Update your status') {
                        document.getElementById('statusUpdater').value = '';
                    }; 
                    if (document.getElementById('statusUpdaterControls').style.display == "none") {
                        document.getElementById('statusUpdaterControls').style.display = "block";
                    }; 
                }; 
            </script>
```

suddenly neither solution works... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have found a solution - by putting the clear content code into an onclick event and keeping them separate, both items are carried out. I would still appreciate any insight into what I was doing wrong earlier however as I must have been doing something silly I can improve on for the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use jQuery and enjoy life again.

Comment: @BNL You don't need a bulldozer to open your front door.

Comment: You don't need semi-colons after the if statement.

Comment: If you put the clear content into a `funtion clearCode() { if (document.getElementById('statusUpdater').value == 'Update your status') { document.getElementById('statusUpdater').value = ''; } }` and then `onfocus="clearContent()`, does it work?

Comment: You claim that your `handler function` works properly when called separately. So why you don't add them spearately with `addEventListener("onfocus", ...)` ?

Comment: @NebulaFox no it doesn't. I experimented with an alert box and it doesn't get past the if statement so that must be where the problem lies - what the problem with it is, however, still eludes me. Perhaps something to do with it not being the proper way to access the value of a textarea...?

Comment: @O&L What are the values of `document.getElementById('statusUpdater').value` and `document.getElementById('statusUpdaterControls').style.display` before the if statement?

Comment: @NebulaFox I'm not really sure as that was one thing I didn't think to check. I have since updated the solution with Jquery and that has worked without a hitch however.

Comment: jQuery does make life a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

The `onfocus` accepts a function, not a string, so:

```
something.onfocus = displayControls;
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. the onfocus tag I was using was inside the textarea tag: <textarea onfocus="if (this.value == 'Update your status') {this.value = '';}">Update your status</textarea> or <textarea onfocus="displayControls();">Update your status</textarea> both work fine. Using them in tandem was the problem.